# How to calculate view_distance of a viewport knowing the appropriate camera?

Tags: python

1. I created a camera in Perspective using Align Active Camera to View (bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view()).
2. Now I switch to the view from this camera using Active Camera (bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view()) + Frame Camera Bounds (bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera())
3. Middle Mouse Click, to change from Camera Perspective to User Perspective
   There is actually an addon that automates 1+2 steps Camera Fit View Add-on 1

Now I want to do step 2+3 without using bpy.ops.

I know how to calculate view_location, view_rotation, knowing the camera parameters, such as location, rotation and all the others.

But for this you need to know view_distance.

I don’t know how to calculate it for a perspective camera.

For an orthographic camera region3d.view_distance=coef * cam.data.ortho_scale. Where coef is constant and can be picked up.

Any help is welcome.